# Run Excel VBA sub from javascript in a secure environment

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I am attempting to do some automation of excel taks using javascipt.  These workbooks already have VBA modules, so I will need to be able to run them from javascript.  My challenge is that when I open a workbook using Javascript I do not get prompted to enable macros.  I am not able to change my trust center settings in my work environment and they are currently set to "Disable all macros with notification," which asks the user to enable macros via a pop-up box if the file is opened manually.

How do I allow the user to enable macros when opening a workbook from javascript?

Error message and code below:

> SCRIPT1004: Cannot run the macro 'C:\Users...\JPO Mdl
>   v07.04.022-FY16MM.01.01_A.xlsm!update_links()'. The macro may not be
>   available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

```
function open_files(A, B, C) 
{ 
 var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
 excel.Visible=true;
 excel.DisplayAlerts = true;
 var wbA = excel.Workbooks.Open(document.getElementById(A).value);
 var wbB = excel.Workbooks.Open(document.getElementById(B).value);
 var wbC = excel.Workbooks.Open(document.getElementById(C).value);

 excel.EnableEvents = false
 excel.ScreenUpdating = false
 excel.Calculation = -4135 //xlCalculationManual enumeration

 var wb_collection = [wbA, wbB, wbC];
 excel.Application.Run(wbA.fullname + '!update_links()');
}
```

Comment: Try `excel.Application.Run(wbA.name + '!update_links()');`  You don't include the workbook path - just the name.

Comment: I tried that, I got the same error only this time without the path.

Comment: Are you able to run the macro using VBA and the same parameters ?  You should be able to enter `Application.Run("'namehere.xlsm'!update_links")` in the Immediate pane and hit enter - that should run the macro and will tell you if it's a macro permissions problem.  Note also you don't include the parentheses on the end of the call.

Comment: Thanks Tim! I got it to work in both js and VBA using your notation.  I was missing some quotation marks. I'm not entirely sure how it is running without the user enabling macros, but I'm not going to lose any sleep over it. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm pretty sure regular macro security doesn't affect what you can do when you're automating Excel: you already have full control over the application and it's assumed you trust whatever code you run using automation.  See (eg) https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857085.aspx#changeauto "By default, when a separate program is used to programmatically start Excel 2013, PowerPoint 2013, or Word 2013, any macros can run in the application that was programmatically started"